# Adding a field in a SP database, wtih ability to paste images from clipboard

Tags: custom-form, list-form

We currently have a database where screenshots are sometimes required to go along with the data. Currently it's a long process, since we have to first save it in a file and then attach it to the entry. Is there a way to include a box within the database entry, where screenshots could be simply pasted?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly more of a hack than a real solution, but it is what I do because I also need to capture screenshots (taken with OneNote keystroke shortcut) and place them in SP.
part of the My
Note: I work in a Windows 7 & Sharepoint Enterprise 2010 w/Foundation environment

- set up a blog on your "personal" site in sharepoint (part of the MyContent area)
- Install Windows Live Writer plugin on your desktop (which is part of the Windows Essentials package, but you can choose to only install the LiveWriter module)
- Use Live Writer to make entries in your SP blog - LiveWriter allows CTRL+V pasting of screen captures
- From the browser, open the SP blog and right click an image to get its SP address
- Use that address to insert an image on a wiki page, link, whatever

It isn't sexy, but it seems quicker than the alternatives.